# ¿Cómo validar rutas dependiendo el tipo de usuario con Laravel y PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Necesito ayuda sobre como utilizar mi variable de sesión para aplicarla en distintas rutas y permitir el acceso dependiendo el tipo de usuario
mi formulario es este

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalogin">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button style="color:#09B8BA;" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">INICIO DE SESION</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form id="modalogin" action="verificarlogin" method="POST" role="form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <center>
        <img src="/storage/bhgaleria/logos/logo5.jpg" class="logimage img-responsive img-circle" alt="Responsive image">
        </center>
        <br>

         <div class="form-group inputmail has-feedback">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Correo Electrónico..." name="correo" required="" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>  
          <div class="form-group inputpass has-feedback">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Contraseña..." name="contrasena" required="" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button id="inici" type="submit" style="width: 50%;" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
          </div> 
      </form>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

después se va a mi ruta

```
Route::post('verificarlogin','AgenciaLAJEcontroller@verificalogin');
```

e inicia sesión en este método del controlador.

```
public function verificalogin(Request $r){
    $usuario=$r->input('correo');
    $password=$r->input('contrasena');

  $arreglo=DB::select('select * from usuarios where correo= :usuarioo and contrasena= :contrasena ',['usuarioo'=>$usuario,'contrasena'=>$password]);

    $renglon =count($arreglo);

        try {

            if ($renglon>0) 
            {

                session_start();
      $juas;
                $_SESSION["usuario"]=$usuario;
      foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) {
       $tipo=$value->tipo_usuario;
      }
      $_SESSION["tipo_usuario"]=$tipo;

                return redirect('/');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div class ='alert-danger'>";
                echo "<h2 align ='center'>Usuario o Password incorrectos</h2>";
                echo "</div";
                return redirect('IniciarSesion');
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
}
```

Ese es mi código, lo que busco es que, si está **logeado** un tipo de usuario, por ejemplo que el **administrador** vea unas páginas en especifico, si es **usuario_normal** tenga el acceso restringido a ciertas páginas, no importa si lo valido en un controlador o en un `middleware`, simplemente que haga la verificación del tipo de usuario ¿Que tengo que hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un Middleware y aplicarlo a las rutas específicas del administrador.

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminRole
```

Ir a app/Http/Kernel.php y añadir el Middleware

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminRole::class,
```

Edita la función handle del AdminRole:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
     }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Y finalmente, añadir el Middleware a tu ruta:

```
Route::get('dashboard', ['middleware' => 'admin', function () {
    //Code here
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendi quieres que dependiendo el tipo de usuario vea o tenga acceso a ciertos modulos, puedes hacerlo restringiendo

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['usuario']['id_rol'] == 1) { ?> 

    <a href="#"> Administrador </a>

<?php } ?>
```

Asi podrias restringirlo, en el caso del `id_rol` pondrias lo que tu tienes para distinguir el tipo de usuario que inicio sesión

Comment: Ya había intentado eso pero me sale "Undefined variable: _SESSION " la variable sesión se crea cuando llega al método del controlador, pero no sé como sacar la variable para usarla en otros métodos

Comment: @EmmanuelBurciaga debes usar el metodo que tiene laravel, para obtener la session `$value = session('key');`